# Приближение числа к нулю

Tags: javascript

Есть `input` с кнопкой. Изначально в `input'е` появляется случайное число от *-100* до *100*. При нажатии на кнопку генерируется случайно число из этого диапазона (к примеру *-67*). Как мне сделать, что бы при повторном нажатии генерировалось число уже из нового диапазона (к примеру от *-67* до *67* смотрите прошлые пример) и так пока число не будет равно *0*?

Я сделал, что бы при нажатии генерировалось новое число, но как сделать, что бы оно новый диапазон учитывало сделать?

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#input'),
    button = document.querySelector('#button');
    
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

input.value = random(-100, 100);

button.onclick = function() {
  // тут не могу додуматься, как новый диапазон взять
  input.value = random(-100, 100);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"><button id="button">Приблизить</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно брать минимальное и максимальное числа из пары `{-value, value}`

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#input'),
    button = document.querySelector('#button');
    
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

input.value = random(-100, 100);

button.onclick = function() {
  if (input.value == 0) {
    button.disabled = true;
    return;
  }
  input.value = random(Math.min(-input.value, input.value), Math.max(-input.value, input.value));
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"><button id="button">Приблизить</button>
```

Comment: Ооо... спасибо!))) Через 4 минуты приму. Сейчас не получается

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что этот код совсем правильный. Ведь, когда значение 0, то оно всё равно ищет рандом, хоть этого и не видно :)

Comment: @Yuri, задизаблил кнопочку)

Comment: @vp_arth, красавчик :D